# How to generate progressive JPG with ImageResizer.net

Tags: imageresizer

I am using the following code to generate a progressive JPG:

```
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(srcFileName, dstFileName, new ResizeSettings("progressive=true"));
```

I am verifying if the JPG is progressive using ImageMagik identify command:

```
identify -verbose dstfile.jpg
```

And I get:

```
Interlace: None
```

I am generating progressive JPG files using Photoshop and identify does report:

```
Interlace: JPEG
```

Looking at documentation, this feature was added on version 3.1 Dec 7 2011. I am using version 3.3.2.447.
I am not sure if I am missing a plug-in or additional commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progressive jpeg encoding is only available with the [FreeImageEncoder](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/freeimage) plugin installed - you must also use the `&encoder=freeimage` command. Neither WIC nor GDI+ offer progressive jpeg encoding, but both WIC and FreeImage support subsampling control.

Also note that progressive jpegs require more mobile device RAM to decompress, and only offer a speed benefit at larger output sizes (I.e, > 600x600)